# On select of UITableViewCell Navigate to New DetailViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Problem: On selection of a particular `uitableviewcell`, a new `DetailViewController` should be opened. I have written the code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but when I click on the cell it is showing me a runtime error.

I have tried calling with `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:jacket animated:YES ];` but when I do my view controller is not getting opened.

Another method I tried is by  `[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"JacketDetails" sender:self ];`.

I have Specified Identifier in the segued has "JacketDetails" in the inspector but here I am getting a run yime error. I have Hooked Segue from `UITABLEVIEWCELL` to `VIEWCONTROLLER`.

When I click on the row `JacketDetailViewController` Should be open. I have Created Class `JacketDetailViewController` and for `New ViewController` I have set the class for this in the inspector.

I don't know why it is showing no segue , I have given the identifier in the inspector and properly hooked from `tableviewcell` to new view controller.

In `JacketDetailViewController` I want to display a list of Jackets. Presently it is blank `ViewController`.

My code is below. Would you please suggest a solution? I am a self-teaching beginner in this field. I might have made some minor mistakes. I have Googled my problem and tried to solve it but I have been stuck here for a few days.

```
TshirtDetailViewController.m

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES ];

    JacketDetailController *jacket =[[JacketDetailController alloc]init];

    NSInteger index =indexPath.row;

    NSLog(@"Row:%d",index);


    NSString *titleString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[jackets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    NSLog(@"%@",titleString);
    jacket.title=titleString;


    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"JacketDetails" sender:self ];


  //  [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:jacket animated:YES ];

}


@end
```

Error in Console:

```
2013-01-07 10:52:21.020 KidsShopee[617:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<UINavigationController: 0x6a5fac0>) has no segue with identifier 'JacketDetails''

*** First throw call stack:

(0x13bf052 0x1550d0a 0xdd24b 0x3e8e 0xa671d 0xa6952 0x92e86d 0x1393966 0x1393407 0x12f67c0 0x12f5db4 0x12f5ccb 0x12a8879 0x12a893e 0x16a9b 0x1b08 0x1a65 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I salute you on what is a solid question showing substantial effort on your part. Please review the edit I made to better understand how to format code blocks, inline code, and non-code blocks--almost everything was inside a code block. In its current, edited, form, I can (and did) upvote your question. The way it was before really deserved a downvote. Don't worry about your English, but please do try to follow normal rules of capitalization, punctuation, and formatting. This will help your readers understand and will help you escape downvotes!

Comment: Thank you for compliments . And you know I tried almost 25 times editing the same question and explaining it properly to my level best..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open view with these lines:

```
    YoutubeViewController *objYoutubeViewController = [[YoutubeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YoutubeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objYoutubeViewController animated:YES];
    [objYoutubeViewController release];
```

In place of YoutubeViewController give your view controller class name & change these lines

According to you & check.Ok if you using storyboard then try like below:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 bookmarkViewController *myVC = (bookmarkViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bookmarkViewController"]
[self presentModalViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

in place of bookmarkViewController give your controller name & check. in drag & drop view

controller in main storyboard give right class name like below images: [image]

in place of my bookmarkViewController name give your view controller name that you want to open.

Comment: Guys ,When i click on any particular cell thn that respective view controller should be opened , Here Just I have took Sample Has jackets  , When i click on it it will show new JacketDetail view controller..So When i click Others option that respective view controller should be opened..

Comment: I am using StoryBoard , I don't know nitWithNibName:@"JacketDetailController" bundle:nil];] will work here.

Comment: Your question is not clear...I think you want on cell click you open another view controller is it right?

Comment: :I am getting error when i try with ur solution  'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/vaibhav/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/6C4B5F57-F133-4352-A9DC-207D5AFBE42F/KidsShopee.app> (loaded)' with name 'JacketDeailViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13bf052 0x1550d0a 0x1367a78 0x13679e9 0x234838 0xdbe2c 0xdc3a9 0xdc5cb 0xdc941 0xee47d 0xee66f 0xee93b 0xef3df 0xef986 0xef5a4 0x3e94 0xa671d 0xa6952 0x92e86d 0x1393966 0x1393407 0x12f67c0 0x12f5db4 0x12f5ccb 0x12a8879 0x12a893e 0x16a9b 0x1ac8 0x1a25 0x1)
terminate called throwing

Comment: For ur Updated Code Should i drag n drop view Controller on canvas or it is creating new viewControlller at runtime?

Comment: in view controller of that view in main storyboard you have given ight class name..

Comment: Ofcourse, you drag n drop view Controller on canvas & then give right class name on that view controller...

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` on the navigation controller! Only your custom viewController can have segues. Call it on self.

Replace

```
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"JacketDetails" sender:self ];
```

with

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"JacketDetails" sender:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try with this-

```
JacketDetailController *jacket =[[JacketDetailController alloc]initWithNibName:@"JacketDetailController" bundle:nil];];///Change string as your nib name.
```

Then if its navigation base application-

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:jacket animated:YES];
```

Then is its viewController base application-

```
[self presentModalViewController:jacket animated:YES];
```

Comment: I am Using StoryBoard this does not work ... See the below runtime error

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you are getting "has no segue with identifier 'JacketDetails'", something is not right with your call to the segue.  I have found that I have problems with seque names working properly unless I copy and paste from the name I gave the seque in the storyboard into my .m file.  Even if the spelling and case is correct, I have found many times, copying and pasting has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you hooked up a segue in the storyboard from the table view cell to another controller, then you don't need any of this code at all to make the segue fire. You should be implementing prepareForSegue to pass the information you need to the detail controller, but no other code is necessary.

Comment: Ok should I write prepareForsegue method in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?? give me some example pls

Comment: @krish No, you shouldn't implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath at all. Make a new project from the master-detail template, and look at what they did in prepareForSegue.